# What does the concept of information mean in biology?

Tags: human-biology, information

We use a lot of borrowed analogies from other sciences; linguistics, computational sciences but what do we really mean, mean with information in living systems?

Comment: bioinformatics can be a research topic.

Comment: The word "information" is not borrowed from any other science, it is borrowed from the English language. The genetic code, for example, was deciphered before most University Computing Science departments were established. This question is both basic and wide. I would start by reading about the genetic code, which is used to encode a certain subset of genetic information. If your background is such that you can't understand the Wikipedia entry or other web accounts, you need to buy and read a molecular biology text.